# Spring Batch : Existing transaction detected in JobRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I get this trace when i run the code below :

```
2023-09-08T16:32:38.217+02:00 ERROR 26472 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step in job job

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.lambda$getObject$0(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:201) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy73.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at com.test.batch.jobConfig$1.execute(jobConfig.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
```

```
    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager mgr;
    @Autowired
    JobRepository jr;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Qualifier("simpleJobLauncher")
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher;
@Bean
    public Job job() throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jr)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jr).tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("helloJob");
                        Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Annotation.class);
                        for (Object bean: beans.values()
                        ) {
                            Job jobbean = (Job) bean;
                            JobParameters jp = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                    .addString("time", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))

                                    .toJobParameters();
                            simpleJobLauncher.run(jobbean, jp);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }, mgr)
                        .build())
                .build();

    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher(JobRepository jr , @Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jr);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

I have tried to lauch it with a separate JobLauncher, with a new TaskExecutor, and so on, maybe i missed something. And i don't use @Transactional at all.

Maybe i don't have the right use of the jobs, if this is the case, please enlighten me

Versions tried :
Java 17 & 20
Spring : 3.1.3
In any case thank you for your time